How to Access a Xaml element for a C# class?
I have a User Control file named B2_CONTENT.xaml, it has a button.
and it source file named G2_CONTENT.xaml.cs, this file has a click event for the button
And I Have another User Control Names B4_CONTENT.xaml, it has a text box.
and these User Controlls all connected in the main window as a Grid Rows
my problem is....
how to make the click event (that from B2_CONTENT) change the text of the text block (that from B4_CONTENT) by accessing the textblock element for the B2_CONTENT file ?
my main question here is: how to ACCESS the elements and data from a UserControll file to another UserControll file ?
i tried to make a static class with a static string, for both files so they can access the variable
and binding it, but that actually didn't work,
what i need is know how to ACCESS the elements and data from a UserControll file to another UserControll file....

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

In general it is a good approach, when the UserControls are abstract and don't know each other.
For your purpose you can probably use a RoutedEvent on the UserControl with the Button, which bubbles up to the MainWindow.
Here you can catch the Event and trigger a method of your other UserControl with the TextBlock.
With this appoach you decouple both UserControls and they can be more easy replaced (if needed).

tbh i didn't try your method, but yours gaves me a hint that i can give the usercontrol a x:Name in Mainwindow.xaml so i can access them in the source file
but anyway THANK YOU <3

well... what a weird thing that a person answer his question
i found out that i can give the usercontrolls (B2_CONTENT & B3_CONTENT) a x:Name in Mainwindow.xaml, then i can access their properties and variables and binding them both
